# Need information on "Service Accounts in Snowflake"

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I wanted to explore on "Service Accounts" in Snowflake. I would need few details like :

--> How service account is different from normal account which we create in Snowflake ?
--> How "service accounts" can be created & configured in Snowflake. Few example of 'service account'.
--> Any example of "service account" set-up in Snowflake document if exists which can be looked upon.

Answer (score 1):

"Service Accounts" are no different than normal user accounts in Snowflake but these are usually used for connecting from external applications to run scheduled tasks, retrieve data or do some kind of regular operations on a scheduled basis. They are created exactly the same way as any other user accounts. Most of these service accounts are either set up with OAuth or Key-Pair authentication mechanism so that there is no need for passing the user credentials. It acts as a headless connection to SF for the aforementioned tasks.
There are some blogs for service accounts and how they are used like:

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/snowflake-service-account-securitypart-1/

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/snowflake-service-account-security-part-2/

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/snowflake-service-account-security-part-3/