# On the Snowflake Users page, what does "Create New User for Service Account" mean? Why does this link show up for two of my snowflake users?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For two of my snowflake user accounts, an icon is showing up on the right that has a popup when I hover over it:

[image: Create New User for Service Account]

Why is this link showing up for two of my users?

Obviously I'm now confused about what these two "users" are and how they were created:

- Are these users really service accounts?
- If so, what is a snowflake service account and how does that differ from a user?
- How do I designate some user accounts as service accounts and what are the pros/cons of doing so?

I've tried clicking the button and it just takes me to the user account details page and I don't see any "create user" type of language on the account details page.

I've tried to find anything in Snowflake's documentation that indicates a difference between service accounts and user accounts but I only find blog posts about how you need to treat your service accouns with care (and implement password rotation policies, etc).

I can't find anything definitive (yet) about designating users as "service acounts".  (The closest thing is [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70343715/need-information-on-service-accounts-in-snowflake) about how service accounts are the same as normal user accounts.

Obviously there is something special about these two user accounts, though, since the snowflake UI is indicating these two users are actually service accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icon appears when a comment is set for the user. This comment can be set by yourself for a user to determine what is the purpose of it.

You may un/set it using the statements:

```
alter user user1 set comment='Create New User for Service Account';    
alter user user1 unset comment;
```

More details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-user.html#alter-user

Comment: Oh, that is hilarious and I'm thoroughly embarrassed!  Thank you!  (As you can tell, I had no idea this was a comment icon!)

Comment: I guess normally it wouldn't be confusing if the comments were something like "Added user / new hire" or "Changed roles / department change". In this case the comment appears to be a tool tip with an instruction option - and that certainly makes it confusing. FWIW I will open a ticket on this to see if the UI team can make it more clear that the icon is showing the comments for the user.